# HBase via JRuby suggestions?

Tags: jruby, hbase

The [HBase shell](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hbase/Shell) is now based on jirb, the JRuby implementation of the interactive ruby shell irb.  Are there any nice tricks for interacting with HBase in JRuby programmatically other than through this shell?

The [example on the Hadoop wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hbase/JRuby) appears to just be straight calls to the Java API; is there anything else I can do?

Answer (score 5):

You can interact directly with the HBase client Java classes.
There's a sample here:
http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hbase/JRuby

Comment: This really should be the accepted answer on this question.  If you're in JRuby, there's no reason not to talk directly with the Java APIs.  They're more feature rich and performant than the Thrift or REST APIs.

Answer (score 1):

There are Thrift and REST APIs for HBase:

http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hbase/ThriftApi
http://hbase.apache.org/docs/r0.20.4/api/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/stargate/package-summary.html#package_description

I'd assume that either of these could be used from Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

There's Rhino http://qslack.com/projects/rhino-a-ruby-hbase-orm/ which is an Ruby ORM for HBase